# Get console's cursor position

Tags: c++, console, command-line-interface

I am kinda new to C++ and i was wondering if is there any way to get the Console's Cursor position (x, y)?

For example, In C# i can use:

Console.CursorLeft for **X** and Console.CursorTop for **Y**

Comment: What kind of console? This will vary hugely by platform/environment/toolkit. Your counter-example is really more of a .NET Platform thing than a C# language feature.

Comment: C++ doesn't offer this. It doesn't even have the concept of a console. If you pick a library do deal with the console, then you can check what's offered in its API.

Comment: Maybe you can look at GUI's such as Qt or wxWidgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you can do this (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi = { };
BOOL ok = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo (hConsoleOutput, &csbi);
```

The current cursor position should then be in `csbi.dwCursorPosition`;

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo).

On Unix platforms, you would use the [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library.